# How to make SQLite3 fetched array more clean?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3 for a web app of mine. Everything works fine. I'm able to access the db, create and everything.

But.. when I retrieve the information using the below code:

```
function db_select($username, $password, $database = 'Railway') {

$db = db_connect($database);

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users ") or die('Query failed');
$rowss = array();

while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    $rowss[] = $row;
}

print_r($rowss);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => John123 [username] => John123 
[1] => foo [password] => foo 
[2] => John [fname] => John 
[3] => Smith [lname] => Smith 
[4] => 21 [age] => 21 
[5] => john@gmail.com [email] => john@gmail.com 
[6] => Male [sex] => Male ) )
```

This array doesn't make sense, how would one individually retrieve the information like fname, lname, age, username, etc?

Is there a way I can convert this into the following form?

```
Array (
username => John123,
password => foo,
fname => John
lname => Smith
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)
```

Since you do not seem to be interested in the column number.

Comment: By default, it fetches both the number and the name. This will only manage to remove the Col number, but not the duplicate values. I still wonder how that exists. It would be really helpful if you could explain that. 

On a brighter note, i've managed to find a solution from the php docs. I'll be posting it here shortly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer from the PHP docs.

```
$row = array(); 

    $i = 0; 

     while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 

         if(!isset($res['username'])) continue; 

          $row[$i]['username'] = $res['username']; 
          $row[$i]['fname'] = $res['fname']; 
          $row[$i]['lname'] = $res['lname']; 
          $row[$i]['age'] = $res['age']; 
          $row[$i]['email'] = $res['email']; 
          $row[$i]['sex'] = $res['sex']; 
          $row[$i]['phone'] = $res['phone']; 
          $i++; 

      } 


print_r($row);
```

Outputs this beautiful array.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[username] => John123 
[fname] => John 
[lname] => Smith 
[age] => 21 
[email] => john@gmail.com 
[sex] => Male 
)
```

Comment: looks good.
$row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
could this have the same outcome ?

Comment: Programatically, yes! Using that, we can retrieve it. But on print_r($), the result isn't the same and thats what i was going for. I know it doesn't matter, but i'm just messing around with these to understand how it works.